# Litecoin mining, AMD Overdrive

Tags: drivers, 13.04, ati, xubuntu

I'm setting up a mining rig using 3-7950's, and have ran into a little bit of a road block. I've seen a few guides using xubuntu 12.10, but none with xubuntu 13.04.

[darth_bunny's guide](http://www.reddit.com/r/litecoinmining/comments/1c4n7i/guide_getting_started_with_n_x_radeon_7950_on/)

[cryptobadger's guide](http://www.cryptobadger.com/2013/04/build-a-litecoin-mining-rig-linux/)

[gentoo (bitcoin)](http://gentoovps.net/setup-bitcoin-mining-gentoo-linux/)

I've tried the first 2 ways on fresh images, but for some reason X never starts...

```
aticonfig --adapter=0 --od-getclocks
ERROR - X needs to be running to perform AMD Overdrive(TM) commands
```

Following the darth_bunny's guide way I built to 13.04 instead of 12.10

```
./amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.3-beta3-linux-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/raring
```

On a side note, whenever I plug the ATI cards in, video (connected to onboard), does not output. I'm guessing this is because the ATI cards are primary? It didn't bother me as I ssh in anyway.

I also have some missing lib's when trying to run cgminer, but that is something to worry about later.

Has anyone solved this on 13.04, or should I just downgrade to 12.10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So for the rest of you I hope this is useful. I disabled the onboard video, and plugged into card.

Re-ran

```
sudo aticonfig --adapter=all --initial -f
```

rebooted, all devices were enabled.

By default cgminer looks for `libudev.so.0`, and will not run until it's happy so I set a link up to the newest version.

```
cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo ln -s libudev.so.1.2.2 libudev.so.0
```

xubuntu 13.04 = happy

Comment: This doesn't work in 13.10 any ideas?

Comment: Without trying it on 13.10 myself I wouldn't know. I recently switched to BAMT (Debian) 1.1 What exact error are you getting.

Answer (score 0):

It appears over-zealous moderators are not allowing me to post a very pertinent answer to this question which also appears elsewhere (the questions are related). So I'll just link to the related question below. Answers are pertinent for Ubuntu 13.10.

[Mining cryptocurrencies with Ubuntu and sgminer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/434591/mining-with-ubuntu-and-sgminer/436098#436098)