# How to Mine w/ 5+ Graphics Cards on Gigabyte 990FXA UD5 (Ubuntu 13.10)

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, ssh

What is the specific process by which to properly set up 5 or more graphics cards for litecoin mining on the Gigabyte 990FXA UD5 or other motherboards running Ubuntu 13.10?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/434591/mining-with-ubuntu-and-sgminer may also be helpful.

Comment: Not a duplicate, as several variables are different. Specifically, 5+ graphics cards, Gigabyte 990FXA UD5 motherboard (although likely applies to other motherboards), and Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: You silly guys this is not a duplicate. This is a totally different question!!